# SQL query error - can't see why?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, yii, ddl

I'm currently reading through this Yii application eBook: http://www.packtpub.com/agile-web-application-development-yii11-and-php5/book - and I'm having a problem inputting the tutorials DDL / SQL statements into PHPMyAdmin without it throwing up errors.

Would someone be kind enough to shed some light on why the following syntax is invalid? It might be something simple but I can't see it:

**SQL statement:**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_issue
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_issue_project FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
REFERENCES tbl_project(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE tbl_issue
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_issue_owner` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`)
REFERENCES tbl_user(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE tbl_issue
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_issue_requester` FOREIGN KEY (`requester_id`)
REFERENCES tbl_user(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE tbl_project_user_assignment
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_project_user` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`)
REFERENCES tbl_project(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE tbl_project_user_assignment 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_user_project` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES tbl_user(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;

INSERT INTO tbl_user (`email`, `username`, `password`)
  VALUES
(`test1@notanaddress.com`,`Test_User_One`, MD5(`test1`)),
(`test2@notanaddress.com`,`Test_User_Two`, MD5(`test2`));
```

**Error Message**

> ```
> Error
> SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE tbl_issue
> ADD CONSTRAINT FK_issue_project FOREIGN KEY (  `project_id` ) 
> REFERENCES tbl_project(  `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
>
>
> MySQL said:
>
> #1005 - Can't create table 'trackstar_test.#sql-c78_127' (errno: 121) (<a    
> href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;
> token=252c0553975923580ca430b6e98c4243">Details...</a>)
> ```

**Note:**

- All the tables in the database are set to innodb as their storage engine.
- I've tried using different foreign key names for each FK, still get the same error.

**Update:**

- After finding no solution to the problem, I deleted by DB, uninstalled Xampp and then redid everything again. Seems to work now. Sorry to not be able to tell future readers exactly what the cause was, but it was most probably to do with my Database config or the information I added to it.

Comment: Does the MySql user have permissions to the `tmpdir` folder?

Comment: Are you able to view the "Details..."?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for coming back to me. I'm working directly in PHPMyAdmin, so I should have all privileges.

Comment: I can't seem to do anything with the: <a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=252c0553975923580ca430b6e98c4243"> - no :/

Comment: Not positive, but I think foreign keys have to be unique, and you have two project_id foreign keys. Also, make sure the tables are innodb, and not myisam.

Comment: @Mark thanks for getting back. I think by default my tables are set to innodb, but how do I check in PHPMyAdmin? Also, I've tried changing the second project_id FK to project_id2 and it still gives me the same error. This is SO frustrating.

Comment: The two foreign keys from `tbl_issue` to `tbl_user` that reference the same column look suspicious. They both are declared with ON DELETE CASCADE. The doc page seems to allow that, saying that only ON UPDATE CASCADE cannot be used on several keys that reference the same column. But is that really so, does MySQL really allow several foreign keys with ON DELETE CASCADE to reference the same column in the parent table? Could the doc page be a bit 'omissive'? And I realise also that the DDL item in the error message is not one of the two I'm talking about.

Comment: @thathurtabit - in PHPMyAdmin, click on the db to display the db, then look in the "Type" column. If you have the table displayed, click the "Operations" tab, then look at "Storage Engine" under the "Table Options". Either place will show you.

Answer (score 0):

**Actual Problem is :**

AS you are Following the book, there are a few insert/ update statements are executed on

```
tbl_proect, 
tbl_issue
```

than you are trying to add Foreign Key Constraint. that checks the table data before applying. So, Here is the actual mistake, may be your tables contain a few records that violate the foreign key constraints. hence phpmyadmin doesnot allow you to alter table and generates error message.

**Solution :**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_project`
TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_issue`
```

Do Only one thing, clear all the tables . Empty tables. . And here's your problm resolved now phpmyadmin allows you to run commands.